# convert decimal to any base java

Tags: java

can anybody help me in this question

Write a program that includes in its MainClass the following:

- A method called convertFromDecimal which takes two integers as parameters. The first integer is the number to be converted and the second integer is the base to be converted to.
  The base value could be any number between 2 (binary) and 16 (hexadecimal). The converted number is returned as a String. The header of the method is as follows: `public static String convertFromDecimal(int number, int base)`
- In your main method declare and initialize an integer. Then print its representation in all numbering systems from 2-16 by invoking the method convertFromDecimal. You should use a for loop for this part.

Hints:

1. Remember that in order to convert a decimal number that includes only an integer part to a base n, you need to use repeated integer division of successive quotients on n saving the remainder in each step until the quotient is zero.
2. Remember that numbering systems with bases 11-16 use letters in order to continue counting after the digit 9. For example, the numbering system with base 12 has the following digits: `{0,1,2,3…..,9,A,B}`

this is my code . i know it's not correct :(

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    convertFromDecimal (1,2);
}

public static String convertFromDecimal(int number, int base) {
 String S="  ";
    int[] converted =new int [base] ;
    while (number>0) {
        int R;
        R=number%base;
        number=number/base;
        char Rchar ;
        switch (R){
            case 10 : Rchar='A';
            case 11 : Rchar='B';
            case 12 : Rchar='C';
            case 13 : Rchar='D';
            case 14 : Rchar='E';
            case 15 : Rchar='F';

        }
            for (int i=0;i<base;i++) 
            {
        converted[i]=R;
                R=number%base;
        }
        for (int m=0;m<base ;m++)
   System.out.print(S +converted[m]);

    }
    return S;        
}
```

Comment: What is your question? I'd suggest figuring out how you would do it be hand on paper so you understand your own algorithm, and then converting that into computer code. As a bonus comment, PLEASE do not use first case upper case variable names. Reserve that naming scheme for Java classes. See variables S and Rchar above.

Comment: ok , help me in any way you like :(  thank you

Comment: Please review [ask].

Comment: i'am sorry :( it's my first question here .. and my English is not good :( @jmoerdyk

Comment: As you later progress you will find that BigInteger Class can do this all for you: `int  intValue = 253; int fromBase = 10; int toBase = 16;  BigInteger number = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(intValue), fromBase); System.out.println(number.toString(toBase).toUpperCase());`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would convert it like described here: http://www.robotroom.com/NumberSystems3.html

A working example (i would prefer a `while` loop here, but the requirement says `for`:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(convertFromDecimal(15,3));
}

public static String convertFromDecimal(int number, int base) {
    String result = "";

    int lastQuotient = 0;

    for(int operatingNumber = number;operatingNumber > base; operatingNumber = operatingNumber/base) {
        result = getRepresantationOfLowIntValue(operatingNumber%base) + result;
        lastQuotient = operatingNumber/base;
    }

    result = getRepresantationOfLowIntValue(lastQuotient) + result;

    return result;
}
```

The requirement in hint 1 you can find inside the while-loop.
The requirement in hint 2 you can find below.

```
private static String getRepresantationOfLowIntValue(int toConvert) {
    if(toConvert >= 0 && toConvert < 10) {
        return "" + toConvert;
    }

    switch(toConvert) {
        case 10 : return "A";
        case 11 : return "B";
        case 12 : return "C";
        case 13 : return "D";
        case 14 : return "E";
        case 15 : return "F";
    }

    return "Error, cannot transform number < 0 or > 15";
    //throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot transform number < 0 or >15");
}
```

Comment: ohh , thank u so much .. but these methods (getRepresantationOfLowIntValue ,, throw new IllegalArgumentException) i have not learned it yet :( , that's mean i can't use it in my code :( .. so what i can be replaced ? @csalmhof

Comment: ok, just a short explanation: this just ensures now higher bases than 16 can be transformed. I edited the code and left the Exception as comment